# Best way to create new window/page/modal for list of JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thank you in advance for your help!

For a project I'm building a page for an animal shelter. On a page I have a list of available animals generated from JSONP data, with a picture and basic data.

I would like to create something so that if the user clicks on the animals picture, it shows the full info for the animal, and all the available pictures.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be? A modal? A new html page? We're only using front end (html, CSS, javascript).

Comment: Try jQuery http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275958/modal-image-galleries-multiple-images?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use bootsrap modal as it fits perfectly to your needs and you can customize it the way you want :

```
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bootstrap modal` is best to show full details.Because users dont want to load pages all the time.

For Bootstrap modal go to this link
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

When you want to display with comments of that blog use `new html page.`