# Applying Modal enlargement

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Greeting.
Hi. I've been applying this modal [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img) into my web. Already got this result. [image]

 but somehow it just applied to the 1st picture only.
How can I get it applied on the rest of pictures (total of pictures would be dynamic, so nvm).
Here's my code.

```
<div class="main-content2">

<ul id="thumbnails">
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="IDGallery_Upl" ItemPlaceholderID="GalleryImg"
        DataSourceID="gridgallery">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <li runat="server" id="GalleryImg"></li>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>

                    <img id="myImg" src="Image/05 Galeri/<%# Eval("GalleryImg") %>" width="200" height="150" alt="<%# Eval("nmGallery") %>"  />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </ul>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01" />
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="gridgallery" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BackboneConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [IDGallery_Upl], [nmGallery], [GalleryImg] FROM [EL_MstGallery] where sts_delete = '0'">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); //IDGallery_Upl

            // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
            var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
            var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01"); // how do I assgn GalleryImg ?
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption"); //how do I assign nmGallery ?
            img.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
            }

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with vb.net so I will remove tag.

Answer (score 0):

take a  look on working sample example I created in
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeevan90/pen/bzYMRx)
I hven't add any aspx codes. 
Your provided code only works for One image as it uses `document.getElementById('myImg')`. Even though you had a list of images, image's ids are same("myImage"). 
So given javascript code only works for first image.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Little research I did a while ago was to find something quite similar regarding this question.
[Modal image galleries - multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275958/modal-image-galleries-multiple-images)
May it comes in handy.